# Does a company ever pay back the money to shareholders?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Lets exclude dividend stocks for this question.

When a company originally goes to the stock market, they're able to raise a lot of money from their shareholders. But does the company ever have to pay that money back to the shareholders in any way, or is it essentially free money for the company?

Comment: Downvoted because of the exclusion of dividends, which are the way companies "pay back" their stockholders.  If a startup company is a flop, and never earns enough to pay dividends, then the stockholders lose their investment.  (Excluding trading: more accurately, the last person to own the stock loses.)

Comment: Will leave this as a comment but I think your question is fundamentally flawed as shareholders pay to own parts of the company. This is hardly free money since the owners are selling their ownership of the company.

Comment: They pay it back immediately. It isn't a loan. You are buying something. You get ownership in exchange for money.

Comment: @jamesqf but dividends are (hopefully) paid from continuing operations, not from Shareholder Equity.

Comment: @jamesqf not every stock comes with dividends. I understand the value of a stock that comes with dividends, I don't understand why the other stocks have value though

Comment: @JoshuaSegal stocks do not "come with dividends".  The Board of Directors *votes to distribute* some of the company's cash as a dividend (and must vote every quarter: issue a dividend? Yes/No.).  That's an important distinction.

Comment: @Joshua Segal: The fundamental expectation is that the stock will pay dividends some day.  Of course at any particular time, a company may be losing money, or be making a profit but plowing that money back to grow the company.  On top of that is the expectation (or perhaps hope is a better word) of many shareholders that the shares will increase in value because of that reinvestment.

Comment: @jamesqf when you say stocks are expected to pay dividends some day, is that for all stocks? If I buy an amazon stock, I'm having trouble finding information on when they will give me dividends and how much

Comment: By the way: One financial instruments where the company issuing them **does** pay back the money later is called a [bond](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bond.asp).

Answer (score 8):

> does the company ever have to **pay that money back** to the shareholders in any way, or is it essentially free money for the company?

You **pay back** loans, but shares are **portions of ownership** (and it doesn't make sense to *pay back* ownership).

What the company *can* do is **buy back** shares; when this happens, there are fewer shares outstanding.

Comment: but why is it valuable to own part of a company if there's no monetary value attached to it?

Comment: @JoshuaSegal your phrase "if there's no monetary value attached to it" confuses me.  I of course know what it means, but not in the context of a functioning, non-bankrupt[see note] company (which by definition has a positive net worth, meaning that the company has *some* value).  [note] Unless it's *about* to file for bankruptcy.

Comment: @JoshuaSegal just think of the example, you and I own a restaurant together, half each.  your share is valuable - **you can sell it**.  similarly imagine if you own a share in a house (perhaps with some siblings).  of course, your share has value.

Comment: @Fattie, thank you for the restaurant analogy, but I think stocks are a bit different. With owning half of a restaurant, you get half of the profits and that's why owning half of the company is valuable. With stocks, you get none of the companies profits. All you get is some kind of documentation that you own .00001% of a company.

Also, if I own half the restaurant and want to sell it to someone and also tell them that they will get none of the profits, no one would want to buy it.

Comment: hi @JoshuaSegal it's totally normal that people buy things that are expensive, because, they will go up in price, even though the thing produces no income.  think about someone buying a Picasso painting, etc etc, not to mention commodities like gold and indeed land.

Comment: note however that many people (like you) think that stocks are conceptually useless - the  *only* reason to own them is that *someone else will buy them from you*.   remember too that companies get taken-over all the time. if apple wants to buy google, the price of the stock will soar because Apple has to secure X% to gain control.

Comment: "With owning half of a restaurant, you get half of the profits and that's why owning half of the company is valuable."  Except for the profits that are plowed back into the business.  And the profits you get as an owner... **are dividends** (presuming of course that the restaurant is run by a corporation).

Comment: @Fattie I think the painting analogy is better, but a painting has value because people like the painting. No one likes to stare at a stock for enjoyment or likes to brag that they own .000001% of a company, so I don't see how a stock has value like a painting.

Comment: Why will the stock soar when apple gains control of google? Just because Apple is doing better?

Comment: @JoshuaSegal the bottom line is that you have some *deep and fundamental* misunderstandings about ownership that we are not able to correct.

Comment: @JoshuaSegal , if someone wants to take over company C, then the stock *of company C* will go up, often dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

investors gain realized value from partial ownership in a company 3 ways:

1. dividends
2. selling their shares upon company issuing stock buybacks [capital gains]
3. selling their shares to other investors upon appreciation of share price from dynamics other than buybacks [capital gains]

#3 is caused by a variety of mechanisms, but is overall driven by sentiment, desirability, profitability, solvency, future revenue/earnings projections, analyst price targets, and a ton of other metrics and ratios.

If a company isn't paying dividends, there's a reason for that - likely that the company sees more value in investing those earnings into R&D and growth, to bring better products/services to market, in order to increase earnings, so that the stock appreciates even more, satisfying investors.

---

a less common one is

4. obtainment of additional stock as a direct consequence of acquisitions and mergers

an even less common one is

5. repayment mandated by bankruptcy law, if a company files for
   bankruptcy

the last one isn't rare because bankruptcy is rare, but rather owners of common stock are often the last ones on a long list of stakeholders who get bankruptcy-related distributions.

Answer (score 1):

When a private company goes public it does an initial public offering (IPO) where it offers a portion of its shares to the public in a new stock issuance.

The capital raised from selling these private shares belongs to the company as well as the early shareholders (founders as well as early investors), allocated based on whose shares are sold.

Owners of publicly traded shares  can get money back (the amount depends on whether share price is higher or lower than what they paid) if:

- They sell it to other investors/traders
- The company does a buyback
- There is a merger/acquisition

Comment: Missing option (albeit it rarely happens): the company is liquidated and the its remaining value is divided among the shareholders.

Comment: In Chapter 7 bankruptcy, common stock rarely  get anything at all because they are last in line when assets are distributed.

Comment: A company might be liquidated by decision of its management, without need of going into bankruptcy (as I said, it is highly unusual)

Comment: The OP didn't ask for how many ways a company can disappear from existence. My answer explained how owners how `Owners of publicly traded shares can get money back'.  I think that you're off on a tangent here.

Answer (score 1):

Stocks that aren't dividend stocks *today* could start paying dividends in the *future*.

And since a company's shareholders (owners) elect the company's board of directors, and the board of directors can declare dividends, shareholders can, indirectly, control whether the company will pay dividends (or buy back stock.)

Profitable, growing companies that *could* pay a dividend but don't are choosing to reinvest profits in the company. By forgoing paying a dividend with today's profits, the company may boost its future profits — and future dividends.

As an example: Microsoft was founded in 1975, went public in 1986, and didn't pay a dividend until 2003. That's a long time with no dividends, but eventually the board of directors decided to pay a portion of profit out to shareholders instead of reinvesting it all. High growth, profitable businesses tend, over time, to become "cash cows".